# Use streams to group Map<Foo,List<Bar>> based on size of the List<Bar>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I'm trying to transform data of this format:

```
Map<Foo, List<Bar>> mapFooToBars;         //start Map
Map<Integer, List<Foo>> mapListSizeToFoos //destination Map
```

I'd like to create a grouping based on the size of the `List<Bar>` for each entry, so that in my output map, I would have a list of all Foos that have 0 Bars together, all Foos that have 1 Bar together, and so on.

I was trying to do this:

```
Map<Foo, List<Bar>> fooBarMap = whatever();
fooBarMap.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(entry -> entry.getValue().size()));
//expected Map<Integer,Entry<Foo, List<Bar>> which
//could be transformed into Map<Integer,Foo> pretty easily
```

I apparently am unclear on how groupingBy works exactly, as this is giving me a "getValue() is undefined for the type Object" error. Somewhere along the line I'm losing the type information about entrySet I guess? It made me wonder if this was not the best way to go about this. Any help appreciated!

Comment: I am not getting this error, there must be something else going on in your real code?

Comment: `Map<Integer, List<Entry<Foo, List<Bar>>>>` is the correct type and it compiles.

Comment: groupingBy will collect entries, not foos

Comment: Ah, you are totally right @JornVernee, I was misinterpreting the return value in my production code. Doh.  Thanks for the responses!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are on the right track.  You should use `groupingBy` but with `mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, toList())` as the second parameter.  This will collect the keys into a list and those lists will be the values of the resulting map.

```
fooBarMap.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(
        e -> e.getValue().size(),
        mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, toList())
    ));
```

above assumes static imports of various collectors

Comment: As I commented above, it turns out my problem was related to a mistaken interpretation of the return value in my production code, but I appreciate this response that helps clarify how to use groupingBy, so I'm going to accept this as the answer. :)